# Is there any way to support custom Bangla font in JsPdf?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I integrated JsPDF in one of my project but it's not showing bangla font properly.

I tried with various ways like **font encoding and addToVFS** and **using @font-face in stylesheet** 
**Sample code to support custom font.**

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.addFont('SiyamRupali.ttf', 'custom', 'normal');

doc.setFont('custom');
doc.text(15, 15, 'মাইক্রোসফট আফিস ট্রেনিং গাইড');
```

I got this result **"þÿ ® ¾ ‡ • Í ° Ë ¸ « Ÿ † « ¿ ¸ Ÿ Í ° Ç ¨ ¿ ‚ — ¾ ‡ ¡**" instead of **"মাইক্রোসফট আফিস ট্রেনিং গাইড"**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to convert your font from [enter link description here](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html)

then,
change the SolaimanLipi-normal.js file->
from,

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
```

to

```
import jsPDF from "jspdf"
```

then,

```
import 'assets/fonts/SolaimanLipi-normal.js';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

const doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFont('SolaimanLipi'); // set custom font (SolaimanLipi)
doc.setFontSize(10); // set font size 10
doc.text('মাইক্রোসফট আফিস ট্রেনিং গাইড', x, y) // and you can write your text with starting co-ordinator

you can check your font is added or not
console.log('fonts', doc.getFontList());
```